# Webcam in VirtualBox (Ubuntu Guest/Ubuntu Host)

Tags: virtualbox, webcam

I have already read the following questions:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/126399/unable-to-start-webcam-in-ubuntu-virtual-box
- [Use my webcam with Ubuntu running in VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4875/use-my-webcam-with-ubuntu-running-in-virtualbox)
- [Integrated webcam cannot be used in VirtualBox Guest XP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209950/integrated-webcam-cannot-be-used-in-virtualbox-guest-xp)

and yet I still have problems getting my webcam (Lenovo Easy Camera) to work under VirtualBox in an Ubuntu (12.04) Host. The host machine is a *Lenovo ideapad U410* running Ubuntu 12.10.

In the host machine the camera is not listed in `lsusb`, yet works fine with all applications (listed under `/dev/video0`).

I was wondering if there is anyway to get the camera working in the guest machine.

`lsusb` in host:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 13d3:5163 IMC Networks 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

**P.S.**

Even though running an Ubuntu guest inside an Ubuntu host machine (inception!) sounds idiotic, I have some good reasons for that!

Comment: VirtualBox not seeing the Webcam?  What application are you using with the Webcam?

Comment: When I start the VBox, there is no application in the host machine which is using the Webcam (at least not that I know of). And in the guest machine I tested the camera with Cheese.

Comment: You might want to look into [Linux Containers for Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LXC) - essentially, a way of isolating a program from the system, without having to virtualize a second operating system. If you need snapshots, btrfs supports them natively.

Answer (score 4):

Late to the party, but I hope this helps someone out there:

On virtualbox 5.0.14 on Ubuntu Host, with Windows 10 Guest. Should work for Ubuntu or whatnot as guest.

Follow the steps found on [Virtualbox Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#idp46730491865824)

**TL;DR**:

Do below when the guest OS is running.

```
~$ VBoxManage list webcams
Video Input Devices: 1
.1 "USB 2.0 Webcam Device"
/dev/video0
~$ VBoxManage controlvm "Windows10" webcam attach /dev/video0
```

In this case,

- my guest OS is `Windows10`
- the host path or identifier pointing to the host webcam is `/dev/video0`
- using default framerate for host Webcam

Comment: Great, this worked for me! I had to install the Extension Pack and enable USB 2.0 in the settings of VB though

Comment: It worked but, the solution given in the next answer is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

To have the integrated webcam working, I did the following:

1. Make sure you have GuestAdditions
2. I installed the Virtualbox Extension Pack for my version (4.3.10 Ubuntu), which you can find here https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds
3. I went to Virtualbox>Settings>USB and added an unnamed device
4. From terminal: `sudo adduser <MyUserName> vboxusers`
5. In the running VM I install the webcam from the virtualbox menu of my (Windows) VM: Virtualbox menu of VM>Devices>Webcam

Not sure that all these steps are strictly needed. I have Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager 4.3.10_Ubuntu
the webcam does not appear in lsusb