# Webcam not detected by Ubuntu 14.04 in VirtualBox

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, webcam

Running Ubuntu on VirtualBox. My webcam is not appearing under `ls /dev/video*`. I've followed the instructions of another post: [Use my webcam with Ubuntu running in VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4875/use-my-webcam-with-ubuntu-running-in-virtualbox). However my camera is still not detected.

Comment: What is the host system and does the camera work with it?

Comment: The host system is Windows 10 and yes the camera does function with it.

Comment: If so, provided that you installed the Extension Pack for your Virtualbox version and the guest additions in Ubuntu, then simply using the the devices menu and selecting your camera will  "connect" to the running VM and "disconnect" from the host.

Comment: @CelticWarrior You should add that as an answer! :)

Comment: @wjandrea Sometimes I feel things are so trivial that I just comment with hints or pointers instead of an answer that IMO should have certain (higher) standards. Besides, in a close inspection this is actually off-topic: It's all about the usage of Vitualbox for Windows, what VM it runs isn't relevant for the method. Now, if after everything done correctly the webcam doesn't work in Ubuntu in spite of being listed (`lsusb`)that's on topic but also and entirely different question and for that being a VM or not is irrelevant.