whatsapp desktop install by wine
Tried to install WhatsApp desktop with Wine, It is not officially available for Linux. WhatsApp doesn't come with exe or msi in Windows. we can only get it through the Windows store, which is the problem.
I tried to manipulate. I installed Wine, dotnet48,c++ distributable, etc necessary regular tools. Then get these files from another Windows computer - WhatsApp.exe WhatsAppNative.winmd WhatsApp.dll  WhatsAppNative.dll WindowsLegacyApi.winmd.
Then tried to run it by wine. No Luck. got error.
Is anyone successful?
Error -
PS /home/dipcb05/Documents/wp> ls                                
WhatsApp.dll  WhatsAppNative.dll    WindowsLegacyApi.winmd
WhatsApp.exe  WhatsAppNative.winmd
PS /home/dipcb05/Documents/wp> wine WhatsApp.exe
0118:err:seh:NtRaiseException Unhandled exception code c0000005 flags 0 addr 0x6fffffc83b7a
PS /home/dipcb05/Documents/wp> 

P.S: I know there are alternatives, and I know there is a web version, but my surroundings use WhatsApp, I take a lot of calls, so I need it on my desktop.

AFAIK this is not going to work. Wine does not work with everything. And whatsapp intentionally does not support video calls in the web version (which is possible, e.g. with the telegram web client - but telegram already has a working linux client anyway)

Whatsapp not being a free software/protocol, there is nothing Ubuntu developers can do about it.

However, you can run a windows VM (and install whatsapp there) and share your camera microphone with it. https://askubuntu.com/q/4875/124466

thanks. gonna try

There is no way to make this work. WhatsApp's website intentionally does not provide this, and there is no reliable way to install the WhatsApp client in a way that will make calls fucntional. For all other WhatsApp functionality, you should use the Web version of the client.
Go to https://web.whatsapp.com/ in a tab, and sign in by taking a photo of the QR code. If you use a Chromium based web browser, you can use the 'kebab' (3 dots) menu to add WhatsApp as an "App" (webapp).
This adds it to the launcher, so you can easily alt-tab between other applications and treat WhatsApp Web as an application, when it's just a website in a window.
Totally worth doing for more than just WhatsApp.

The question says OP knows there is an web app, but OP needs to make calls with it. So the only valid answer (as of current state of whatsapp and ubuntu) is, this is not possible.

Read the first 6 words again.

@popey Just putting this out there, but there are more respectful ways to say the same.  Such as "There is no mechanism to do this, WhatsApp intentionally does not provide this in the web version, and there is no reliable way to install the WhatsApp client in Ubuntu to make calling functional."

Ok. Edit the post if you feel that way.
